# Mathlink works strangely

Tags: warning-messages, mathlink-or-wstp, error-tracking

I have problem when using mathlink, the source code is quite simple:

```
void MAXF(char* ex1, char* ex2, char** result){
   MLINK lp;
   int pkt;
   MLEnvironment env;
   env = MLInitialize(NULL);
   if (env == NULL) return;
   int argcs = 4;
   char *argvs[5] = {"-linkmode", "launch", "-linkname", "math -mathlink", NULL};
   lp = MLOpen(argcs, argvs);
   if (lp == NULL) return;

   *result = malloc(100);
   sprintf(*result, "0");

   MLPutFunction(lp, "Exit", 0L);
   MLClose(lp);
   MLDeinitialize(env);
}
```

and in main, i call it by:

```
char* test;
MAXF("0", "0", &test);
```

However, after running, the terminal always shows this line:

```
In[2]:=
```

I believe that there is a problem, but I can't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 9.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, which is Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (64bit), this does not happen. I used the following code, which extends your example into a [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example)](http://sscce.org/). The C code can be found [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WU6JYq25) and you might want to adapt the setting for `"TargetDirectory"` and `"Libraries"`:

```
<< CCompilerDriver`
src = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WU6JYq25", "Text"];
prog = CreateExecutable[src, "out", "ShellCommandFunction" :> Print, 
  "ShellOutputFunction" :> Print, "Libraries" -> {"ML64i3"}, 
  "TargetDirectory" -> "/tmp"]
```

After starting the program in the terminal I get no output

```bash
patrick@lenerd:~/tmp$ ./out 
patrick@lenerd:~/tmp$
```

Comment: I don't know why the error occurs in my system, even when I remove the two lines:

    *result = malloc(100);
    sprintf(*result, "0");

I use ubuntu 12.04 64 bit also. I compile by 
gcc -o main main.c -lML64i3 -lm -lpthread -lrt -lstdc++

Comment: @Loi.Luu When you try my code above, which uses the automatic compilation from within *Mathematica*, does the `In[2]:=` appear too?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how to set the TargetDirectory and Libraries correctly. I paste your script into Mathematica console and nothing happens.

Comment: I have edited the code block. Just copy it completely into a *Mathematica* notebook and evaluate it. After it `prog` contains the path to the built executable which you can start by simply calling it in a terminal. In my case (now here on OSX) it is `/private/tmp/out`, in your case it will be something different. Just copy the output to a terminal.

Comment: I still get this error, I mean the `In[2]:=` still appears..

Comment: @Loi.Luu How about using a debugger to check what exactly happens?

Comment: Which debugger are u talking about? The code is quite simple though.